# Why my MDAC 2.7 reference doesn't work on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, reference, windows-10, adodb, mdac

I have 2 machines, one with Windows 7 64-bit, one with Windows 10 64-bit. Both have Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.5 installed.

I have an old application that still uses ADODB (MDAC 2.7).

The project compiles and runs perfectly on the Windows 7 machine. But in the Windows 10 machine the reference to ADODB has a yellow warning sign and the project does not compile. The 2 errors I get say:

- "The referenced component 'ADODB' could not be found."
- "Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit."

If I replace the MDAC 2.7 reference with MDAC 2.8 in the Windows 10 machine, then the project compiles OK, but an error appears later when I actually try to use the ADODB objects.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.